# Remove unwanted boxes with aspect ratios

Tags: python, opencv

now i am learning python opencv especially from http://opencvpython.blogspot.com i am having this problem to find license plate after i use find contour function and bounding rectangle function, as an example i got 3-5 boxes like in the front window, background trees and many more. can anyone help me with this since i so stressed out to find the answer. and sure i already use many preprocessing like :

1. grayscale
2. threshold
3. morphology

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#import image
im = cv2.imread('sample_1.jpg')
#convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#apply bilateral filter 
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,11,17,17)
#preparing a kernel matrix 5x5
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
#tophat ops
cv2.morphologyEx(gray,cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)
edged = cv2.Canny(tophat,30,200)
dilated = cv2.dilate(edged,kernel,iterations = 3)
#finding contour
(cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
screenCnt = None
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c,True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,0.02*peri,True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    print cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingrect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
    roi = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite(roi.png',roi)
    if len (approx)==4
        screenCnt = approx
        break
cv2.imshow("test",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The code is mostly from browsing and reading blogs. the point is with this code i got multiple box in the license plate. all i want is got only the license plate,crop it and then do some character segmentation.

Comment: the more specific question is how to filter those boxes using aspect ratios?

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific about what it is that needs to happen. What is the input parameters and what is expected out of it. Also give specific details about what you have already tried.

Comment: I've heard also about epsilon, and does any one know what does epsilon to do with the aspect ratios?

Comment: hofnarwillie : my progress is i already convert it to grayscale image,bilateral filter, and a (5,5) kernel filter for tophat function after that edge detection which is canny, dilated process after that find contour function.

Comment: what it needs to be happen is i only want one box which is the license plate , since i got many unwanted and annoying boxes other than the license plate

Comment: @user3794777 Specifics always help.  Can you post your code and the sample image that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @John1024 : i have difficulty posting a code sir , i always get message like my question isnt complete

Comment: I put your code in the question where it belongs.  It is true that your rep is too low to embed images.  However, stackoverflow will upload the image to an image sharing site and provide a link to the image.  Without such a link, your problem is not reproducible and therefore not a good for stackoverflow: see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, note that you code, as posted, has unbalanced quotes.

Comment: Does the boxes you are looking for, in the image, have constant (or similar) sizes? You could just ignore the ones whose size doesn`t match to a license plate. Also, I`m not sure if you are doing it, but you should combine strategies, and slowly refine your results, since there is no guarantee any technique isolated will work for you - for instance, when you use a morphological filter, you probably get a result closer to what you want; if you refine it, throwing out results with size and aspect ratio that doesn't match to a plate, you might get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#import image
im = cv2.imread('sample_1.jpg')
#convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#apply bilateral filter 
gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray,11,17,17)
#preparing a kernel matrix 5x5
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
#tophat ops
cv2.morphologyEx(gray,cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)
edged = cv2.Canny(tophat,30,200)
dilated = cv2.dilate(edged,kernel,iterations = 3)
#finding contour
(cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(edged,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)
screenCnt = None
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c,True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c,0.02*peri,True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    print cv2.contourArea(c)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingrect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
    roi = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite(roi.png',roi)
    if len (approx)==4
        screenCnt = approx
        break
cv2.imshow("test",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: iam new to this opencv python and also to programming so mostly in that code i got from browsing and reading blogs.i wanna put some picture but i dont know why i got message saying that i have insufficient points. the point is with this code i got multiple box in the license plate. all i want is got only the license plate,crop it and then do some character segmentation